# Calculated Table Cumulative Total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to add a column with a cumulative total in a calculated table with this `DAX`:

```
CALCULATE(sum('Eighty20'[LTV]), FILTER( ALLSELECTED( Eighty20 ), Eighty20[Rank Asc] <= MAX (Eighty20[Rank Asc])))
```

However, I'm getting the overall sum in each field rather than the cumulative total. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the total is that you filter based on :

```
Eighty20[Rank Asc] <= MAX (Eighty20[Rank Asc])
```

This returns all the rows because it checks if the current Rank Ac <= max, what is always true. To get cumulative:

```
yourColumn =
var curRank = Eighty20[Rank Asc]
return CALCULATE(sum('Eighty20'[LTV]), FILTER(Eighty20, Eighty20[Rank Asc] <= curRank))
```